# what is the quickest way to style django model form fields one by one

Tags: django, django-templates, modelform

I have `ModelForm` which renders successfully.

this is my **forms.py** form

```
class UploadPostsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'date', 'file']
```

this is how it looks in **templates**

[image]

I want it to look like **below** using **bootstrap5**

[image]

what is the fastest and easiest way to do it?
I have found **three ways**.

***1. adding custom template tags***

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='addclass')
def addclass(value, arg):
    return value.as_widget(attrs={'class': arg})
```

```
{% load myfilters %}

<form action="/contact/" method="post">
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    {{ form.subject.label_tag }}
    {{ form.subject|addclass:'MyClass' }}
    <span class="helptext">{{ form.subject.help_text }}</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

***2. defining styles in each form fields or all at once***

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'myfield': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        }
```

***3. overriding `__init__` method***

```
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'myfieldclass'})
```

***what is the best way to do this?***

Comment: Second is preferable.

Comment: More easiest way to use **[django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/)**  here is simple [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html)

Comment: Thank You. yeah `django-widget-tweaks` looks great

Answer (score 1):

`django-crispy-forms` can solves this problem. It will let you control the rendering behavior of your Django forms in a very elegant and DRY way.

Repo: https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms

Simple Tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html